# Graphite Aggregate data for less than a second interval

Tags: graphite, whisper

I am using graphite to display our application transaction stats. The txns are generated at around 20 per second and is processed and pushed to graphite. So there are more than one data point per second.

My problem is, how can i aggregate this data in graphite? Currently my graphite only plots data points **per minute.**

My data is like this :

> servername.syspulse.alert

. Currently i have only one server.

This is my storage schemas file

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:3d,1min:90d,10min:180d
```

And this is storage-aggregation.conf file

```
[syspulse]
pattern = \.syspulse\.alert$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

and default entries in the file are below this..
```

Any pointers will be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

`pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:3d,1min:90d,10min:180d`

should work to store data with 1 sec resolution.

Have you defined this schema *before* creating the metrics ?
Otherwise you should recreate them (or resize them) because schema is used at creation time only.

To confirm that your whisper file have the correct schema, you can use the `whisper-info.py` script:

`whisper-info.py /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/your/metric/path.wsp`

Comment: I defined the schema before creating the metrics. My problem was that i have more than one data point for a single second. Decided to use statsd to aggregate date from my application before sending it to graphite.